# Metal Shader mix fragment receiving wrong color value

Tags: xcode, shader, scenekit, arkit, metal

I have 2 passes in Metal:

1 - node_pass

2 - mix_pass

debugged it with xCode:

```
fragment half4 node_fragment (NodeColorInOut vert [[stage_in]])
{
    float4 color =  float4((vert.center.x + 1.0) * 0.5 , (vert.center.y + 1.0) * -0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    return half4(color);
}
```

***vert.center*** is a data from node's center calculated at ***node_vertex***. It doesn't matter why. I have my reasons.

And from the XCODE debugger i can confirm ***"float4 color"*** returns [**0.416**,**-0.345**,0.0,0.0]. Which means it is returning the half4 color correctly with the Y ([1]) value -0.345.

So far so good!

The problem is when it goes to the mix_pass.

**- mix_vertex:**

```
vertex MixColorInOut mix_vertex (VertexInput in [[stage_in]],
                                        constant SCNSceneBuffer & scn_frame [[buffer (0)]])
{
    MixColorInOut out;
    out.position = in.position;
    out.uv = float2 ((in.position.x + 1.0) * 0.5, (in.position.y + 1.0) * -0.5);
    return out;
}
```

**- mix_fragment:**

```
fragment half4 mix_fragment (MixColorInOut vert [[stage_in]],
                            texture2d <float, access :: sample> colorScene [[texture (0)]],
                            depth2d <float, access :: sample> depthScene [[texture (1)]],
                            texture2d <float, access :: sample> colorNode [[texture (2)]],
                            depth2d <float, access :: sample> depthNode [[texture (3)]])
{
…
// this part runs only when it's a pixel inside the node
float3 center_map = colorNode.sample(s, vert.uv).rgb;
…
}
```

In the debugger *(selecting a pixels inside the node)* float3 **center_map** is [0.416,**0.0**,0.0,0.0].

**0.0** for the second component when it should be **-0.345**.

Why is that? It's crazy because the debugger at node_fragment shows the value **-0.345** for Y ([1]).

In theory, it should be the exact color value [0.416,**-0.345**,0.0,0.0] confirmed with debugger previously.

When i do center_map.x it returns the correct value 0.416, which means it is getting the x color value from node_fragment.

But when i do **center_map.y** it is 0.0, which is NOT the value shown in the debugger from node_fragment.

Any clues what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What pixel format is being used for the first pass? Most pixel formats are **unsigned**, including `MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB` which SceneKit defaults to.

If you're only working with two color components `MTLPixelFormatRG32Float` is a  good candidate.

Comment: It's the same pixel (inside the node) for both passes. When i say i checked in the debugger, it means i checked the same pixel on first node_fragment return half4(color); from the first pass, and then the second final pass mix_fragment.

Comment: PLEASE, someone DOWNVOTE this answer since it's should be just a comment (This answer is not useful), definitely NOT AN ANSWER.
I don't have enough rep to downvote it myself.